# Am I right that Reed-Solomon codes can be used to implement arbitrary-parity RAID schemes?

Tags: coding-theory, error-correcting-codes

I guess the question does not apply just to CS as I'm trying to understand how it applies to RAIDs, but I guess it's maybe the most suitable place to ask anyway.

There's a lot of info that RS codes are often used to implement second parity for RAID-6. There are some systems that implement triple-parity.

Am I right that by using enough Reed-Solomon parity bits I can implement 4-way parity etc., up to arbitrary-way parity (as long the the stripe is long enough, e.g. by writing each n bit stripe as k data bits + t parity bits)?

I'm just surprised why, if it's true, parity counts > 3 are not implemented in any production systems.

Comment: R-S error detection and correction get more complex with increasing length.

Comment: @YvesDaoust do you mean that what I asked is possible, but would just quickly become impractical (prohibitively slow)?

Comment: It is obviously possible. And probably economically unreasonable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Reed-Solomon code applied to 512-byte (4096-bit) sectors can support up to $n=2^{4096}$ drives in an array, of which any fraction may be parity drives. The limits of real-world RAID setups come from practical considerations, not theory.

RAID can defend against the random failure of up to $t$ drives, but it can't defend against a power surge or fire or software bug or anything else that destroys the entire array. There is some $t_\text{max}$ such that for $t\ge t_\text{max}$ the probability of failure is largely independent of $t$ because failure modes that can't be prevented by RAID dominate. Probably $t_\text{max}\approx 3$.

Answer (score 1):

More broadly, the issue of repairing Reed-Solomon codes currently employed in industry has been discussed in the literature. It is important to find algorithms with low-bandwidth repair schemes for codes of short lengths with typical redundancies.

A recent paper is a good place to start since it has tables of current best repair schemes for $[n,k]$ Reed-Solomon codes over $\mathbb{GF}(2^8)$ with $4≤n≤16$ and redundancy $r=n−k∈{2,3,4}. $The tables cover most known codes currently used in the distributed storage industry. For convenience, I have reproduced a figure from that paper which has examples of the codes used in industry.

[image]

See the paper available [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.11015).